# Extracting distinct objects from a complex object using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a collection that contains a list of complex objects, "SubCategory".  SubCategory contains "Category".

I can iterate through my collection and see all object, and drill down through to Category.

How can I, using Linq, extract a distinct list of Categories?

I initially tried this in a foreach loop:

```
if (!categoryList.Contains(baseline.ContentCategory)
{
    categoryList.Add(baseline.ContentCategory);
}
```

But that just does not work, and I think a Linq solution would be more elegant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subCategoryList.Select(s => s.Category).Distinct()

Comment: Thanks... I tried this but my var always ends up null.  Thoughts?

Comment: because distinct is using deferred execution, so you probably want to do something like this.subCategoryList.Select(s => s.Category).Distinct().ToList()